# How to use Aggregate in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How do I define the following MongoDB aggregate query in mongoose:

```
db.contacts.aggregate([{$group: { "_id": { code: "$Code", name: "$Name" } } }])
```

The objective of the query is to pull a list of distinct codes and names.

My current model code is:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var fields = {
    Code: { type: String },
    Name: { type: String }
};

var contactSchema = new Schema(fields);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Contacts', contactSchema);
```

Router looks like this:

```
api.contacts = function (req, res) {
Contacts.find({ AgencyTranslation: /^BROADCASTING/ }, function(err, contacts) {
  if (err) {
    res.json(500, err);
  } else {    
    res.json({contacts: contacts});
  }
});
```

I tried various variations, also looked up the sample code at: [mongoose API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate), but I cannot seem to get it working.

(Note: the above query does work in the MongoDB console.)

Comment: Just call `Contacts.aggregate()`. The method is defined in the model and the syntax is just the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
Contacts.aggregate({$group: { "_id": { code: "$Code", name: "$Name" } } }, function(err, contacts) {
   ...
});
```

Or, with `$match` if you need this `AgencyTranslation: /^BROADCASTING/` condition

```
Contacts.aggregate([
  { $match : { AgencyTranslation: /^BROADCASTING/ } },
  { $group: { "_id": { code: "$Code", name: "$Name" } } }
], function(err, contacts) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Hi, Can you Also Explain How We Can Use .graphLookup() in Mongoose