# How do I filter to return a subset of a mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filter, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My objective is to query mongoDB for a subset of an array within an array.

For example, in the 'whole Data Set' (below), I would like to get all of the chorePerson records that have a personID of '5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577'

**Whole Data Set**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411031",
        "affiliation": "liss_family",
        "year": 2019,
        "weekNumber": 9,
        "chart": [
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411054",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Catbox",
                        "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411053",
                        "person": "Joe_2512",
                        "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                        "chore": "Sweep",
                        "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411052",
                        "person": "Tom_2510",
                        "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                        "chore": "Trash",
                        "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411051",
                        "person": "M_2513",
                        "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                        "chore": "Dishes",
                        "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411050",
                "ordinal": 0
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104f",
                        "person": "Joe_2512",
                        "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                        "chore": "Catbox",
                        "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104e",
                        "person": "Tom_2510",
                        "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                        "chore": "Sweep",
                        "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104d",
                        "person": "M_2513",
                        "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                        "chore": "Trash",
                        "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104c",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Dishes",
                        "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104b",
                "ordinal": 1
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104a",
                        "person": "Tom_2510",
                        "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                        "chore": "Catbox",
                        "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411049",
                        "person": "M_2513",
                        "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                        "chore": "Sweep",
                        "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411048",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Trash",
                        "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411047",
                        "person": "Joe_2512",
                        "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                        "chore": "Dishes",
                        "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411046",
                "ordinal": 2
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411045",
                        "person": "M_2513",
                        "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                        "chore": "Catbox",
                        "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411044",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Sweep",
                        "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411043",
                        "person": "Joe_2512",
                        "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                        "chore": "Trash",
                        "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411042",
                        "person": "Tom_2510",
                        "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                        "chore": "Dishes",
                        "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411041",
                "ordinal": 3
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411040",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Catbox",
                        "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103f",
                        "person": "Joe_2512",
                        "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                        "chore": "Sweep",
                        "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103e",
                        "person": "Tom_2510",
                        "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                        "chore": "Trash",
                        "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103d",
                        "person": "M_2513",
                        "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                        "chore": "Dishes",
                        "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103c",
                "ordinal": 4
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103b",
                        "person": "Joe_2512",
                        "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                        "chore": "Catbox",
                        "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103a",
                        "person": "Tom_2510",
                        "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                        "chore": "Sweep",
                        "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411039",
                        "person": "M_2513",
                        "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                        "chore": "Trash",
                        "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411038",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Dishes",
                        "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411037",
                "ordinal": 5
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411036",
                        "person": "Tom_2510",
                        "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                        "chore": "Catbox",
                        "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411035",
                        "person": "M_2513",
                        "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                        "chore": "Sweep",
                        "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411034",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Trash",
                        "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411033",
                        "person": "Joe_2512",
                        "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                        "chore": "Dishes",
                        "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411032",
                "ordinal": 6
            }
        ],
        "date": "2019-02-25T21:56:50.737Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

**Desired results**

So here is the desired result I want.  Only the chorePerson results that match personID of '5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577' :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411031",
        "affiliation": "liss_family",
        "year": 2019,
        "weekNumber": 9,
        "chart": [
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411054",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Catbox",
                        "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411050",
                "ordinal": 0
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104c",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Dishes",
                        "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104b",
                "ordinal": 1
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411048",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Trash",
                        "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411046",
                "ordinal": 2
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411044",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Sweep",
                        "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411041",
                "ordinal": 3
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411040",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Catbox",
                        "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103c",
                "ordinal": 4
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411038",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Dishes",
                        "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411037",
                "ordinal": 5
            },
            {
                "chorePerson": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411034",
                        "person": "emily",
                        "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                        "chore": "Trash",
                        "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411032",
                "ordinal": 6
            }
        ],
        "date": "2019-02-25T21:56:50.737Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

I have looked at the following two articles, and it seems like aggregation might be the way to go

https://www.devsbedevin.net/mongodb-find-findone-with-nested-array-filtering-finally/

[How to use Aggregate in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712022/how-to-use-aggregate-in-mongoose)

**Background**

Here is my schema:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const chorePersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        person: {type: String, requried: true},
        personID: {type: String, required: true},
        chore: {type: String, required: true},
        choreID: {type: String, required: true},
    });

    const chartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        ordinal: {type: Number, required: true},

        chorePerson : [{ type:chorePersonSchema }]       
    });


    // create the schema
    const ChoreChartSchema = new Schema({

        affiliation: {type: String, required: true},
        weekNumber: {type: Number, required: true},
        year: {type: Number, required: true},

        chart:[{type: chartSchema}],

        date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    })

    module.exports = ChoreChart = mongoose.model('cm_chorechart', ChoreChartSchema)
```

**Tried this**

This is what I have tried:

```
ChoreChart.aggregate([
{ $match : { affiliation: 'liss_family' } }
,{ $group: { "_id": { personID: '5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577' } } }
]
)
.then(stuff =>{
    return res.status(200).json(stuff);
})
.catch(err => {
    return res.status(401).json(err);
})
```

The above returns:

```
  [
      {
          "_id": {
              "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577"
          }
      }
  ]
```

Then I tried changing the group to the following:

```
,{ $group: { "_id": { "chorePerson.personID": '5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577' } } }
```

Which returned:

```
 "errmsg": "FieldPath field names may not contain '.'.",
```

Comment: What is the filter condition for your nested data? Do you want to get only single element inside the `chorePerson` array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7510657/anthony-winzlet ... I will update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation

```
ChoreChart.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "affiliation": "liss_family" } },
  { "$addFields": {
    "chart": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$chart",
        "as": "cc",
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$cc._id",
          "ordinal": "$$cc.ordinal",
          "chorePerson": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$$cc.chorePerson",
              "as": "dd",
              "cond": { "$eq": ["$$dd.personID", "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577"] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: spot on dude !  THANK YOU !  I was beating my head against the wall on this !  Thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7510657/anthony-winzlet - can you message me?  I have another question about this.

Comment: Please ask a new question. I will try to answer

Comment: can you chat with me?

Comment: Could you let me know where are you from?

Comment: I am in the bay area

Comment: I don't know how to start a chat ... is this the process ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7510657/anthony-winzlet - new question asked:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009324/how-do-i-return-an-aggregate-of-sub-arrays-with-a-filter-on-the-top-most-array

Comment: Actually I don't have system right now. I try to answer with mobile screen