# How do I return an aggregate of sub arrays with a filter on the top most array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to get all the choreperson data for a specific ordinal

Here is the initial data:

```
    [
        {
            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411031",
            "affiliation": "liss_family",
            "year": 2019,
            "weekNumber": 9,
            "chart": [
                {
                    "chorePerson": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411054",
                            "person": "emily",
                            "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                            "chore": "Catbox",
                            "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411053",
                            "person": "Joe_2512",
                            "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                            "chore": "Sweep",
                            "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411052",
                            "person": "Tom_2510",
                            "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                            "chore": "Trash",
                            "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411051",
                            "person": "M_2513",
                            "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                            "chore": "Dishes",
                            "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411050",
                    "ordinal": 0
                },
                {
                    "chorePerson": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104f",
                            "person": "Joe_2512",
                            "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                            "chore": "Catbox",
                            "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104e",
                            "person": "Tom_2510",
                            "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                            "chore": "Sweep",
                            "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104d",
                            "person": "M_2513",
                            "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                            "chore": "Trash",
                            "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104c",
                            "person": "emily",
                            "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                            "chore": "Dishes",
                            "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104b",
                    "ordinal": 1
                },
                {
                    "chorePerson": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104a",
                            "person": "Tom_2510",
                            "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                            "chore": "Catbox",
                            "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411049",
                            "person": "M_2513",
                            "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                            "chore": "Sweep",
                            "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411048",
                            "person": "emily",
                            "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                            "chore": "Trash",
                            "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411047",
                            "person": "Joe_2512",
                            "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                            "chore": "Dishes",
                            "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411046",
                    "ordinal": 2
                },
                {
                    "chorePerson": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411045",
                            "person": "M_2513",
                            "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                            "chore": "Catbox",
                            "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411044",
                            "person": "emily",
                            "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                            "chore": "Sweep",
                            "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411043",
                            "person": "Joe_2512",
                            "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                            "chore": "Trash",
                            "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411042",
                            "person": "Tom_2510",
                            "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                            "chore": "Dishes",
                            "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411041",
                    "ordinal": 3
                },
                {
                    "chorePerson": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411040",
                            "person": "emily",
                            "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                            "chore": "Catbox",
                            "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103f",
                            "person": "Joe_2512",
                            "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                            "chore": "Sweep",
                            "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103e",
                            "person": "Tom_2510",
                            "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                            "chore": "Trash",
                            "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103d",
                            "person": "M_2513",
                            "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                            "chore": "Dishes",
                            "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103c",
                    "ordinal": 4
                },
                {
                    "chorePerson": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103b",
                            "person": "Joe_2512",
                            "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                            "chore": "Catbox",
                            "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041103a",
                            "person": "Tom_2510",
                            "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                            "chore": "Sweep",
                            "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411039",
                            "person": "M_2513",
                            "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                            "chore": "Trash",
                            "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411038",
                            "person": "emily",
                            "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                            "chore": "Dishes",
                            "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411037",
                    "ordinal": 5
                },
                {
                    "chorePerson": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411036",
                            "person": "Tom_2510",
                            "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                            "chore": "Catbox",
                            "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411035",
                            "person": "M_2513",
                            "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                            "chore": "Sweep",
                            "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411034",
                            "person": "emily",
                            "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                            "chore": "Trash",
                            "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411033",
                            "person": "Joe_2512",
                            "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                            "chore": "Dishes",
                            "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411032",
                    "ordinal": 6
                }
            ],
            "date": "2019-02-25T21:56:50.737Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

What I would like to do is return all the choreperson data for a particular  year, week number and specific ordinal (eg : 2)

So the final result would look like this:

```
    [
        {
            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411031",
            "affiliation": "liss_family",
            "year": 2019,
            "weekNumber": 9,
            "chart": [
                {
                    "chorePerson": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a1347041104a",
                            "person": "Tom_2510",
                            "personID": "5c703e5c094c084af05d8432",
                            "chore": "Catbox",
                            "choreID": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411049",
                            "person": "M_2513",
                            "personID": "5c745b80a3b3cb3a449b9605",
                            "chore": "Sweep",
                            "choreID": "5c6f168bf09a1e0a50164683"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411048",
                            "person": "emily",
                            "personID": "5c6e3c74b9f5ed0016b00577",
                            "chore": "Trash",
                            "choreID": "5c6f16b2f09a1e0a50164686"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411047",
                            "person": "Joe_2512",
                            "personID": "5c6ed442c30c29281cd75425",
                            "chore": "Dishes",
                            "choreID": "5c7063476ee2723a24707b9d"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5c7464a26b47a13470411046",
                    "ordinal": 2
                }
            ],
            "date": "2019-02-25T21:56:50.737Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

I am thinking that I need to filter on the chart.. then fill in the chorePerson... but I am having an issue with filtering the ordinal and I don't know how to get the choreperson details in the result

Here is what I have so far:

```
    ChoreChart.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "affiliation": affiliation, "year": week.year, "weekNumber": week.number } },
        { "$addFields": {
          "chart": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$chart",
              "as": "cc",
              "in": {
                "_id": "$$cc._id",
                "ordinal": "$$cc.ordinal",
                "ordinalString": "$$cc.ordinalString",
                }
              }
            },
            "$chart": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$cc.ordinal",
                  "as": "ccc",
                  "cond": { "$eq": ["$$ccc.ordinal", "2"] }
                }
          }
        }}
      ])
```

***UPDATE***

asking new question instead of tacking it on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
ChoreChart.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "affiliation": affiliation, "year": week.year, "weekNumber": week.number } },
    {
        $addFields: {
            chart: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$chart",
                    cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.ordinal", 2 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) replaces existing field and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) filters inner array. Additionally since your `ordinal` is a number you also need to specify number not string in your query.

Comment: This works ...  thanks !!   Just a quick question.. why don't I have to include any code to get choreperson data ... it just seems to "come along for the ride" .. ?

Comment: @MLissCetrus `$filter` does not "reshape" the data. It just decides if whole document from `chart` array should or should not appear in final result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6238977/mickl thanks ... do you know of any REALLY GOOD mongo db tutorials that explain this kind of stuff ?

Comment: Just browse the docs, there's a lot of good examples that can help you to understand how these operators work

Comment: Who marked this question "This question already has an answer here:"   that question uses '$project' in the answer, while this question uses '$addFields' -- I don't know the subtle differences... but the answers appear to be different.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6238977/mickl - hey.. I need a little more help... I would like to modify your answer to return only the chores for a SPECIFIC PERSON for the ordinal

Comment: @MLissCetrus hey, could you open another question - I cannot help you now but I promise I will take a look later