# How do I merge these two separate aggregate queries into a single query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have posted two questions concerning aggregation queries in mongo.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889387/how-do-i-filter-to-return-a-subset-of-a-mongoose-schema/54891052#54891052) Gets all the chores for a *specific person*

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009324/how-do-i-return-an-aggregate-of-sub-arrays-with-a-filter-on-the-top-most-array) Gets all the chores for *all people* on a *specific ordinal (day)*

Now, however, I would like to combine both of those queries into a single query. Returning only the chores for *a specific person on a specific day*.

Here is what I have thus far :

```
        ChoreChart.aggregate([
            { "$match": { "affiliation": affiliation, "year": weekYear, "weekNumber": weekNumber } },
            { "$addFields": {
              "chart": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$chart",
                  "as": "cc",
                  "in": {
                    "_id": "$$cc._id",
                    "ordinal": "$$cc.ordinal",
                    "ordinalString": "$$cc.ordinalString",
                    "chorePerson": {
                      "$filter": {
                        "input": "$$cc.chorePerson",
                        "as": "dd",
                        "cond": 
                            { 
                            "$and": [ 
                                {"$eq": ["$$dd.personID", personID]},
                                {"$eq": ["$$cc.ordinal", ordinal ]}
                            ] }                        
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }}
          ])
```

This is what I get for an ordinal of 4, however, my output includes ordinals that I am not interested in.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e2d482cd8593e00162d0568",
    "affiliation": "800_800",
    "year": 2020,
    "month": "January",
    "weekNumber": 5,
    "weekStart": "01/26/2020",
    "weekEnd": "02/01/2020",
    "chart": [
      {
        "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda785",
        "ordinal": 0,
        "ordinalString": "Sunday",
        "chorePerson": []
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda783",
        "ordinal": 1,
        "ordinalString": "Monday",
        "chorePerson": []
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda780",
        "ordinal": 2,
        "ordinalString": "Tuesday",
        "chorePerson": []
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda77e",
        "ordinal": 3,
        "ordinalString": "Wednesday",
        "chorePerson": []
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda77c",
        "ordinal": 4,
        "ordinalString": "Thursday",
        "chorePerson": [
          {
            "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda77d",
            "person": "Jo",
            "personID": "5e2890268c63351b7c07dc26",
            "phone": "8008008001",
            "chore": "DC 1",
            "choreID": "5e2929cf285338cb8cf375fc"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda77e",
            "person": "Jo",
            "personID": "5e2890268c63351b7c07dc26",
            "phone": "8008008001",
            "chore": "DC 2",
            "choreID": "5e2929cf285338cb8cf375fd"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda77a",
        "ordinal": 5,
        "ordinalString": "Friday",
        "chorePerson": []
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda778",
        "ordinal": 6,
        "ordinalString": "Saturday",
        "chorePerson": []
      }
    ],
    "date": "2020-01-30T16:23:44.713Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

***This*** is what I really want :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e2d482cd8593e00162d0568",
    "affiliation": "800_800",
    "year": 2020,
    "month": "January",
    "weekNumber": 5,
    "weekStart": "01/26/2020",
    "weekEnd": "02/01/2020",
    "chart": [
      {
        "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda77c",
        "ordinal": 4,
        "ordinalString": "Thursday",
        "chorePerson": [
          {
            "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda77d",
            "person": "Jo",
            "personID": "5e2890268c63351b7c07dc26",
            "phone": "8008008001",
            "chore": "DC 1",
            "choreID": "5e2929cf285338cb8cf375fc"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5e330310c66e9e4084cda77e",
            "person": "Jo",
            "personID": "5e2890268c63351b7c07dc26",
            "phone": "8008008001",
            "chore": "DC 2",
            "choreID": "5e2929cf285338cb8cf375fd"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "date": "2020-01-30T16:23:44.713Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: what do you mean by specific ordinal day ? Do you mean by `"ordinalString": "Sunday" etc..` ??

Comment: ordinal ... is the day of the week in this case, eg 0 = sunday, 1 = monday, 2 = wednesday ... etc  The 'ordinalString' is there for human readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
ChoreChart.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "affiliation": affiliation, "year": weekYear, "weekNumber": weekNumber } }, {
        "$addFields": {
            "chart": {
                "$map": {
                    /** $filter in input to retain only objects in array that match ordinal filter */
                    "input": { $filter: { input: '$chart', as: 'c', cond: { "$eq": ["$$c.ordinal", ordinal] } } },
                    "as": "cp",
                    "in": {
                        /** $mergeObjects to merge chorePerson filtered array field on each 'chart.chorePerson' */
                        $mergeObjects: ['$$cp', { chorePerson: { $filter: { input: '$$cp.chorePerson', as: 'each', cond: { "$eq": ["$$each.personID", personID] } } } }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 ])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5riFP4uhpQU)

Comment: Thank you so much... I just can't wrap my head around the Mongo stuff... I guess I am too much of a linear thinker, instead of a "set thinker" - thanks again !